# Projects owned by me not displayed in "My projects"

Tags: google-apps-script

As user A, in script.google.com/home/all, I see projects whose owner is B.
As user B, in script.google.com/home/my, I see nothing, but I see them in home/all, again with owner B.
Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: Did user B share his projects with user A?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot really tell. I tried so many things. But originally the projects were created by A (me, the developer), and later I managed to make B the owner (B a more generic name), so that mails sent by the script showed B as sender, not A. The projects are scripts attached to forms, scripts attached to sheets, and webapp scripts.